# MySQL query to select all record inside a date range excluding a date interval

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL table is like this

```
TOURS 
| id | date_active_from | date_active_to
| 1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31
| 2 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-09-15
| 3 | 2017-07-01 | 2017-10-20
| 4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00
```

I have two select field to search for tours active in a specific time range

```
SELECT *
FROM tours
WHERE ( ( date_active_from <= userdatefrom OR date_active_from = '0000-00-00' ) AND ( date_active_to >= userdateto OR date_active_to = '0000-00-00' ) )
```

now we would like to add one or more time interval where tour is not active like

```
| id | date_active_from | date_active_to | date_notactive_from | date_notactive_to
| 1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 | 
| 2 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-09-15 | 2017-06-10 | 2017-06-20 |
| 3 | 2017-07-01 | 2017-10-20 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
| 4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
```

how can i query excluding time interval where tour is not active?

Comment: Instead of breaking it into two "where" clauses, use BETWEEN which is inclusive.  The dates not active shouldn't necessarily be values because they can be calculated as exclusions from the active dates.  This does not hold true if the "not active" dates are within the active time frame, in which case you could either create exclusions, or create additional rows with more fine grained active dates.  In either case, adding these columns is, IMO, not a good way to solve this problem. It is fairly obvious that this table is a child.  That would mean that you can have many sub records for dates?

Comment: To decide active/inactive, we need an encompassing time range to include both intervals. Is your criteria the entire calendar year of 2017? If so, id 1 would have no inactive period?

Comment: I edited my question because some tours can be always active and have no from / to date. I also add an example of date interval excluded, tour 2 is available from 2017-06-01 to 2017-09-15 but not from 2017-06-10 to 2017-06-20. Tour 1,3 and 4 don't have inactive periods

Comment: This is really confusing. How do you determine if an ID has a notactive values? Do you need to do math to figure that out or you are pulling those from another database?  For ex: ID1 has a full year active so there aren't any inactive values(meaning 0). This would make sense if your inactive values are based on the calendar year of 2017. But ID3 has Active values for 3 months, but the notactive values are also 0. Why is that?

Comment: Are city tours and user has a form where it insert the time interval that he is in town. Notactive time interval is a new request and are not in the table yet, maybe the only way to accomplish is to add a child table.  City tour: 1 is available from  2017-01-01 to 2017-12-31, 2 is available from  2017-06-01 to 2017-09-15 but is suspended from 2017-06-10 to 2017-06-20, 3 is available from 2017-07-01 to 2017-10-20 and 4 always available all year long every year.